# Repeated measures anova with ezanova amd the wid function

Tags: r, anova

So I'm trying to run a repeated measures anova. I basically have two IVs with scores from 1-7 and a dv. Every participant has a score in both IVs and the vd of course whitch makes them within subjects. Even after consulting `?ezAnova` I can't figure out what my "wid" is.

My code looks like this:

```
ezANOVA(data=df,
    wid = 
    dv = df$scoredv,
    between = .(df$scoreIV1, df$scoreIV2))
```

or this:

```
model<- lme(df$dv ~ df$iv1 + df$iv2, random = ~1|subject/df$iv1 + df$iv2, data=df)
```

In this case I don't know what belongs in the subject function.

As far as I understood wid or subject is the number of the participant but I dont have a special column for that. Do I have to create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ez's docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/ez.pdf), `wid =` should be the participant's univocal ID, in this case.

It's good practice to always have one (especially for data wrangling operations or individual-level data analyses). You can probably create one quickly just for the purpose with

```
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
```